# Retornar os dados de uma tabela caso não exista em outra

Tags: php, sql

Possuo um ambiente onde existe duas formas de login e tabelas "Usuários" e "Estabelecimentos", essas tabelas são bem parecidas e eu preciso retornar essa consulta com base no e-mail digitado no formulário de login.

Eu estou tentando retornar selecionando diretamente em ambas as tabelas, porém não está correto. ex:

```
SELECT * FROM {$tabelas->estabelecimentos} as estabelecimento, {$tabelas->usuarios} as usuario WHERE estabelecimento.email = %s OR usuario.email = %s LIMIT 1
```

Porém o que eu preciso é o seguinte:
"Selecione da tabela estabelecimentos onde email = email OU caso não exista selecione da tabela usuarios onde email = email"

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você pode usar a função ISNULL.

```
ISNULL(estabelecimento.email,usuario.email)
```

Olhe se o link abaixo pode te ajudar.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms184325.aspx